# Android Observable Pattern with 2 Observables

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sensors, observable

Inside my activity I have a broadcast receiver that I initialize as such:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateViews();
    }
};
```

updateViews() is a function inside the activity that is only used within the broadcast receiver. How can I create this receiver as a separate class that can play with the views (rotate, delete etc.) of my activity?

In addition, I have a compass within the activity. It works, however I would also like to make the compass a separate class that can send data to the activity. It will not change the views of the activity but only update certain double/float values.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {    }

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create this receiver as a separate class...?

This answer assumes that "separate class" means you want a `BroadcastReceiver` that is defined in its own source file and is not an inner class of an activity.  Before offering a solution, I'll ask, what do you expect to gain by this? Do you have multiple activities that will use the receiver?  If not, it's best to leave it as an inner class of the single activity that uses it.  If you don't like using the anonymous inner class in the code you posted, you can declare is as an inner class:

```
private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // As an inner class of the activity, this receiver has
        // access to all activity members.
        updateViews();
    }
}
```

If you really want it as a standalone receiver, the example code below is a starting point.  Be sure to register/unregister the receiver in your activity's `onResume/onPause` callbacks.  The example includes code for a less safe approach, using a plain activity reference, and a safer approach using a weak reference.  Only one is needed.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // For less safe use
    private MyClientActivity mActivity;
    // For more safe use
    private WeakReference<MyClientActivity> mActivityRef;

    public MyBroadcastReceiver(MyClientActivity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mActivityRef = new WeakReference<MyClientActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Less safe
        mActivity.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
        mActivity.someActivityMemberMethod();
        // etc

        // More safe.  Guards against failure to unregister
        // this receiver when activity is paused.
        MyClientActivity act = mActivityRef.get();
        if (act != null && !act.isDestroyed()) {
            mActivity.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
            mActivity.someActivityMemberMethod();
            // etc
        } else {
            // Error: Activity failed to unregister this receiver
        }
    }
}
```

> I would also like to make the compass a separate class that can send
>   data to the activity

Same assumption and question as above:  Will the compass be used by multiple activities?  If not, it's probably best to make it an inner class of the single activity.  If there *are* multiple client activities, consider using a [started-service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).  It could notify activities of sensor events using a local broadcast or an event bus such as [greenrobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).